# Gradle copies all the files if at least one is not up-to-date

Tags: gradle

For instance, I've got the following task:

```
task testCopy(type: Copy) {
    from ("folder/copy_from")
    into ("folder/copy_to")

    eachFile {println it.name}
}
```

Unless the inner files of the folder `copy_from` are touched, task works fine. As soon as I change, let's say one file in the folder `copy_from`, then Gradle begins to copy all the files from `copy_from` folder into `copy_to` instead of copying only one changed/added file.

Is this behaviour expected? Is there a way to make Gradle copy only changed/added file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes based on [this github issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1643) and [gradle discuss](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/incremental-build-of-copy-tasks/13278/7):

> The build is incremental in the sense that the copy task only executes
>   when things have changed but it isn’t incremental itself, in that it
>   only copies inputs that have been modified.

I couldn't find a propper solution, but one solution is just splitting your task into smaller ones with specific types.

```
task copy1(type: Copy) {
       into 'build/out'
       from ('src') {
            include 'docs/*.txt'
       }
       eachFile {println it.name}
}

task copy2(type: Copy) {
    into 'build/out'
    from ('src') {
        include 'docs/*.md'
    }

    eachFile {println it.name}

}

task copy3 {
    dependsOn copy1, copy2
}
```

It's not exactly what you want but it improves the performance by reducing files to copy.
when you change a text file and run `gradle copy3` it just copies the text files not md files.

**UPDATE:**
Ant copy task doesn't have this problem
from it's [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html):

> By default, files are only copied if the source file is newer than the destination file, or when the destination file does not exist. However, you can explicitly overwrite files with the overwrite attribute

So you can use ant copy task instead, as we can [use ant tasks from gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html):

```
task copyFromAnt {
    doLast {
        ant.copy(todir: 'build/out') {
            fileset(dir: 'src')
        }
    }
}
```

ant logs the files it copies so you can check the log with help of `gradle -d` and `grep`:

```
gradle copyFromAnt -d | grep "\[ant:copy\]"
```

and to see just the files it copies with out up-to-dat and etc. you can use the below command:

```
gradle copyFromAnt -d | grep "\[ant:copy\] Copying"
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I see. The issue is that I've got like 3k files with the same extension meaning that even if I changed only one of them I should wait to copy 3k files again. Sadly.

Comment: That's huge. Thank you a lot. I also wonder if it's possible to print the count of files to be copied with `ant.copy`?. With Gradle Copy task we could use `eachFile` to count files. Maybe you are aware of this?

Comment: There is not any powerfull feature like `eachFile` in ant but and loggs the copied files and up to date files and ... . As essages logged from Ant appear in the Gradle output we can use gradle `-d` option and `grep` to find the ant messages of copy task. I updated the post with an example.